# How to get one with children?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have simple query:

```
    $query = $qb->select('c, s')
        ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.streets', 's')
        ->where('o.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', 'London')
        ->andWhere('s.numbers > :number')
            ->setParameter('number', 10000);

    $result = $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I would like get City and streets by relations. If city and streets with numbers > 10000 exists this query is working good, but if city exists and doesn't have numbers > 10000 then this query return null. Why, if I use leftJoin, not join?

How can I get city, even if city doesn'y have streets?

Comment: A condition on the inner table of an outer join must be ANDed to the ON, otherwise it turns the join into an inner join.

Comment: @dnoeth so how can I make it?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in symfony, I write my queries in SQL :-)

Comment: can you try removing `s` from select?

Comment: If I remove s from select, then andWhere not working.

Comment: @juzit like this? `qb->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.streets', 's')` it should works as the alias is named on `c.streets`

Answer (score 0):

If your entity `Streets` entity is mapped to your `City` entity, then you don't need such query.

In twig, simply do this:

```
{% for steet in city.streets %}
    <div>steet.name</div>
    <div>steet.length</div>
    <div>steet.etc</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Else, to correct your query, it should be like this:

```
public function getCityStreets(City $city, $street) {
    // param $city :: Entity City
    // param $street :: Integer
    return $this->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('c', 's')
                ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c')
                ->join('AppBundle:Streets', 's')
                ->where('c.name = :city')
                ->andWhere('s.number = :street_number')
                ->andWhere('s.city = :street_city)
                ->setParameters(array(
                    new Parameter('city', $city->getName()),
                    new Parameter('street', $street),
                    new Parameter('street_city', $city->getId()),
                ))
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
}
```

- `o.name` isn't valid in your query... `o` wasn't set anywhere
- `'c.streets', 's'` isn't valid as well, you can to join `Steets`, but not as a column from `City`
- `leftJoin` can be `join` as you've mapped `Streets` to `City`, there should not have any `street.city` with `NULL` value

**Good practices tip** : Entities name are never plural